# How to end regex on first search

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
<center>DB Results:</center><center><b><br>ripster.ultima</b></center><center><b><br>raghav.jhavar</b></center></center></td></tr></table>
```

I want to extract "ripster.ultima" and "raghav.jhavar", so I used the following regex:

`(?<=<center><b><br>)(.*)(?=<\/b><\/center>)`

Now, this works in some cases, but not in all: https://regex101.com/r/imO8A8/4

In the link above, the first example is a single line. When I put in a single line, it does not select the individual strings. However, if its separated by a new line as seen in the second example, the strings I want are highlighted.

How do I get the strings in the first example?

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with regex is generally not a good idea.  Consider using an XML parser instead.

Comment: I just need to get 1 part of the html body, not sure if I want to use an external library for such a small purpose.

Comment: The data you want to match seems to always be in the same format (xxxx.xxxx), maybe you could match that format instead of the HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don’t need to group the first and the last patterns

```
<center><b><br>(.*?)<\/b><\/center>
```

Comment: This gives me a pattern error. `?  The preceding token is not quantifiable`

Comment: Just updated it. Html can be really messy so it is best to use an xml parser if you need to parse anything beyond this use case

Comment: This is pretty much my only use case. Not sure who is down voting, and why they are without specifying any reason.